# One-liner to list old versions of files in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to work out a linux one-liner to list only files that are earlier version duplicates of files in a directory. e.g.:

```
filenames:

foo-bar-foo-1.3.42.jar
foo-bar-foo-1.2.21.jar
foo-2.3-foo-bar-3.1.2.jar
foo-2.3-foo-bar-3.2.4.jar
bar-foo-1.24.jar
bar-foo-2.0.jar
foobar-foobar-3.4.1.jar
barfoo-barfoo-1.2.1.jar

expected output:

foo-bar-foo-1.2.21.jar
foo-2.3-bar-3.1.2.jar
bar-foo-1.24.jar
```

This is similar to the question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185193/remove-the-low-version-number-of-file , but that one relies on being able to set a file seperator on the first dash and mine have at least two dashes. I've had some limited success trying to tweak it like this:

`ls -vr *.jar | awk -F-[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+ '$1 == name{system ("ls \""$0"\"")}{name=$1}'`

but it misses those with only 2 numbers in the version.

and using this gets caught up on files like foo-2.3-foo-bar-3.1.2.jar:

`ls -vr *.jar | awk -F-[0-9]+.[0-9]+ '$1 == name{system ("ls \""$0"\"")}{name=$1}'`

I can also use gsub to get a variable that contains everything but the version number, but I can't figure out how to use it to ultimately get my expected results.

`ls -vr *.jar | awk -F- '{gsub("-"$NF,"",$x)}{print $x}'`

I am open to not using awk if there's a better solution (I'm not terribly familiar with it). I'm working on RHEL in bash with sed also available. However, it must be a one-liner that can be used directly on the command line.

Comment: You need to learn more about [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) software such as [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort now has a `--version-sort` option which is the hero here.

```
#!/bin/bash

# let awk remember the previous file prefix (p1) and previous file name (f1)
# if the current prefix (p2) matches the previous prefix (p1), then 
# print the previous filename (f1)
awk '{
    # remember the previous values
    p1=p2
    f1=f2
    # save the current filename
    f2=$0
    # strip the version and extension
    sub(/[0-9\.]+.[a-z]+$/, "")
    # save as the current prefix
    p2=$0
    if (p1 == p2) {
        # print the previous filename if this prefix is the same as the previous
        print f1
    }
}' <(sort --version-sort <(for f in *.jar; do echo "$f"; done))
```

And now for the one-liner :)

```
awk '{p1=p2; f1=f2; f2=$0; sub(/[0-9\.]+.[a-z]+$/, ""); p2=$0; if (p1==p2) {print f1}}' <(sort -V <(for f in *.jar; do echo "$f"; done))
```

Results:

```
bar-foo-1.24.jar
foo-2.3-foo-bar-3.1.2.jar
foo-bar-foo-1.2.21.jar
```

Comment: this is excellent! since ls also has a version sort, I tried removing the sort and piped 'ls -v *.jar' into the awk to shorten it up and seem to be getting the same results. Do you see any pitfalls with using ls over sort?

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is potential risk when parsing the output of ls. It's probably fine 99% of the time, but I tend to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET_DIR=/opt/svn_opensource/oss/public-maven-dependencies/
cd $TARGET_DIR

for PREFIX in `ls *.jar | sed 's/-[0-9].*\.jar/-/g' | uniq -d`; do
  COUNT=`ls -d -- $PREFIX[0-9\.]*.jar | wc -l`
  if [[ $COUNT -gt 1 ]]; then
    echo $PREFIX '['$COUNT']'
    i=1
    for FILES in `ls -d -- $PREFIX[0-9\.]*.jar | sort`; do
      if [ $COUNT -gt $i ]; then
         rm -rf $TARGET_DIR$FILES
         ((i=i+1))
      else
         echo 'retain------------' $FILES
      fi
    done
  fi
done
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.